# let the system go to sleep by a command

Tags: android, linux, sleep

In `Linux` or `Android`, `/sys/power/wake_lock` there is such a file, if I find that the system does not enter sleep, can I use echo `XXX > /sys/power/wake_lock` to unlock, let the system go to sleep.

This will affect the system?

Comment: you want to put your device in sleep mode, (by turning of the LCD light) ?

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long

Comment: no, some system processes often wake up the system.I went to remove the lock in some cases.